# How to send a date with offset to the server while adding a new entry into Ignite UI ig.Grid table

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

I'm using Ignite Ui 16.1 igGrid with RESTDataSource.
Please, consider following configuration of one of the grid's columns:

```
{
                   headerText: $.i18n._("From"),
                    key: "start",
                    validation: true,
                    required: true,
                    dataType: "date",
                    editorType: "date",
                    format: "HH:mm",
                    editorOptions: {
                        validatorOptions: {
                            dateInputFormat: "HH:mm",
                            OnBlur: true,
                            OnChange: true
                        }
                    },
                    readOnly: false
}
```

When a new row is adding, in the payload of the post/create request  `start:"/Date(1470636037642)/"` is sent to the server, which is parsed by the default MVC model binder as UTC date. This is absolutly in unison with Ignite Ui documentation that states all dates are sent in UTC.

Could you, please, point me out, how to configure this column, so a date with an offset to be sent to the server. I would like to know user's timezone. Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be [this page of the docs](http://www.igniteui.com/help/using-igniteui-controls-in-different-time-zones) will be helpful.

Comment: `validation`, `required`, `editorType`, `editorOptions` and `readOnly` are not properties of [igGrid.columns](http://igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ui.iggrid#options:columns) object. You're probably referring to [igGridUpdating.columnSettings](http://igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ui.iggridupdating#options:columnSettings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the timezone offset info manually in the transaction object.

```
features: [
    { 
        name: "Updating",
        editRowEnding: function(evt, ui) {
            ui.values["offset"] = ui.values["CreateDate"].getTimezoneOffset();
        }
    }
]
```

If you use igGrid MVC Wrapper to deserialize the transaction log you will need to add an additional field (in this case named "offset") to your model.

Comment: `var offsetValue = 3;
var createUrl = $('#grid').igGrid().dataSource._postTmpl;
$('#grid').igGrid().dataSource._postTmpl = createUrl.substring(0, createUrl.indexOf("?")) +"?offset=" + offsetValue;`